# Calculating network download speed

Tags: java, networking, download

I have written the follwing code to calculate download speed using java.
But it is not giving correct results.What is the problem?.Is there a problem with my logic , or is it a problem with java networking classes usage?I think it is a problem with the usage of java networking classes.Can anybody tell me what exactly the problem is?

```
/*Author:Jinu Joseph Daniel*/
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class bwCalc {
    static class CalculateBw {
            public void calculateUploadBw() {}
            public float calculateDownloadRate(int waitTime) throws Exception {
               int bufferSize = 1;
               byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize]; // buffer
               BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("https://www.google.co.in/").openStream());
               int count = 0;
               long startedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
               long stoppedAt;
               float rate;
                while (((stoppedAt = System.currentTimeMillis()) - startedAt) < waitTime) {
                    if ( in .read(data, 0, bufferSize) != -1) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Finished");
                    break;
                }
            }
            in .close();
            rate = 1000 * (((float) count*bufferSize*8 / (stoppedAt - startedAt)) )/(1024*1024);//rate in Mbps
            return rate;
        }
    public float calculateAverageDownloadRate() throws Exception{
        int times[] = {100,200,300,400,500};
        float bw = 0,curBw;
        int i = 0, len = times.length;
        while (i < len) {
            curBw = calculateDownloadRate(times[i++]);
            bw += curBw;
            System.out.println("Current rate : "+Float.toString(curBw));
        }
        bw /= len;
        return bw;
    }
}
public static void main(String argc[]) throws Exception {
    CalculateBw c = new CalculateBw();
    System.out.println(Float.toString(c.calculateAverageDownloadRate()));
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not via a link.

Comment: So what results *is* it giving?

Comment: the result is increasing when i increase time

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your code...

- you're not checking how many bytes you are reading
- testing with Google's home page is useless, since the content size is very small and most of the download time is related to network latency; you should try downloading a large file (10+ MB) - **UNLESS** you actually want to measure latency rather than bandwidth, in which case you can simply run ping
- you also need to give it more than 500ms if you want to get any relevant result - I'd say at least 5 sec
- plenty of code style issues, but those are less important

Comment: number of bytes read is same as count ..that's why i increment it when one read is finished

Comment: Wrong - count is number of reads. It would be the same only if you read one byte at a time.

Comment: so the read() will not wait till the specified number of bytes read..i mean if the specified number of bytes is not available,it will read only the available data..?so i should check the size of data in buffer each time?... How can i do that?

Comment: The read method returns the number of bytes it read (if it reads anything). Refer to the javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which will calculate the average download rate for you in KBs and MBs per second you can scale them by 8 to get the rate in bits per second.

```
public static void main(String argc[]) throws Exception {
        long totalDownload = 0; // total bytes downloaded
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // size of the buffer
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // buffer
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                new URL(
                        "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.15/linux-headers-2.6.15-020615_2.6.15-020615_all.deb")
                        .openStream());
        int dataRead = 0; // data read in each try
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // starting time of download
        while ((dataRead = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
            totalDownload += dataRead; // adding data downloaded to total data
        }
        /* download rate in bytes per second */
        float bytesPerSec = totalDownload
                / ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000);
        System.out.println(bytesPerSec + " Bps");
        /* download rate in kilobytes per second */
        float kbPerSec = bytesPerSec / (1024);
        System.out.println(kbPerSec + " KBps ");
        /* download rate in megabytes per second */
        float mbPerSec = kbPerSec / (1024);
        System.out.println(mbPerSec + " MBps ");
    }
```

Comment: This only calculates once though after the transfer completes. Should happen within the while loop.