# Concept to Transfer Rater per Second while downloading

Tags: java

i am being given a task from my senior to come out with a function to show size transfer rate per second.

I have to download a file from web with my java code and display the transfer rate per second while downloading the file.

[image]

please note the code below is not totally mine, it was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039660/calculating-network-download-speed)
The code below only can calculate transfer rate after the download has finished, but i currently have no idea how to make the code to display transfer rate every second, any conceptual idea or code suggestion?

```
public static void main(String argc[]) throws Exception {

long totalDownload       = 0;                      // total bytes downloaded
final int BUFFER_SIZE    = 1024;                   // size of the buffer

byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];               // buffer
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(

    new URL(
            "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com:8080/5MB.zip"
          + "")
            .openStream());

 int dataRead        = 0;                          // data read in each try
 long startTime      = System.nanoTime();          // starting time of download
 while ((dataRead    = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
    totalDownload  += dataRead;                   // adding data downloaded to total data
    System.out.println(totalDownload);
}

/* download rate in bytes per second */
float bytesPerSec = totalDownload
    / ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000);
System.out.println(bytesPerSec + " Bps");

/* download rate in kilobytes per second */
float kbPerSec = bytesPerSec / (1024);
System.out.println(kbPerSec + " KBps ");

/* download rate in megabytes per second */
float mbPerSec = kbPerSec / (1024);
System.out.println(mbPerSec + " MBps ");
}
```

Comment: The answer to this requires that you look at other parts of your code. The assorted math functions you've pasted in needs to be invoked by something during the download of the code that knows how big the final object is.  There is no simple way to guide you to the 'use this code in this other way' from what you have provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show a transfer rate during the download is to show the average transfer rate to download the portion downloaded so far.

In other words, after you downloaded each kilobyte, you calculate the current transfer rate (total data so far/time needed to download) and update your display.